# How can i display subtotal in Add To Cart button Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, price

I'm using Magento 1.9 and I want to display subtotal in the cart button.
I tried with this code

`<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>`

But it still displays `0.00` in the cart, even after I added a product to cart.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access current subtotal wherever you want this way

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal()
```

So, your try should be...

```
$subtotal = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($subtotal);
```